# Performing transformations on files

Tags: vba, excel

The code opens some files and does some transformations. I am looking for syntactical help where I can do the same thing I am doing now but speed it up. I can supply some of the calls code if requested.

Can anyone help me optimize this? I need help limiting my access to workbooks in order to speed this up.

```
Public Sub generateIRandCRshocks(scenPath As String, scenNames() As Variant, curveNameToMarketData() As Variant, curveData() As Variant, curveNames() As Variant, currToRiskFree() As Variant, termBuckets() As Variant, exportPath As String)

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim thisScen As Long, thisCurve As Long, thisBucket As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long, thisRow As Long
    Dim thisArr() As Variant
    Dim thisArrRow As Long, thisCurveMapRow As Long, thisCurveDataRow As Long, thisRiskFreeRow As Long

    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet

    'ensure data to be searched is sorted
    Call quicksort(curveData, 2, 1, UBound(curveData, 1))
    Call quicksort(curveNameToMarketData, 1, 1, UBound(curveNameToMarketData, 1))

    'create data structure to hold shocks
    Dim arrshocks() As Variant
    ReDim arrshocks(1 To UBound(scenNames) * UBound(curveNames) * 2, 1 To 3 + UBound(termBuckets))

    'list column names to be read in ***code assumes all files have the same format!
    Dim readcols() As Variant
    ReDim readcols(1 To 9)
    readcols(1) = 1 'RF attribute1
    readcols(2) = 2 'RF attribute2
    readcols(3) = 3 'RF attribute3
    readcols(4) = 4 'RF attribute4
    readcols(5) = 5 'RF attribute5
    readcols(6) = 6 'RF attribute6
    readcols(7) = 7 'RF attribute7
    readcols(8) = 10 'Shock Value
    readcols(9) = 11 'Shock Type

    thisRow = 1
    For thisScen = 1 To UBound(scenNames, 1)

        'MsgBox (scenNames(thisScen, 1))

        'open file
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(filename:=scenPath & scenNames(thisScen, 1) & ".csv", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
        sourceWB.Activate
        Application.EnableEvents = True

        Set sourceWS = sourceWB.Worksheets(scenNames(thisScen, 1))
        lastrow = lastWSrow(sourceWS)

        'read into array and concatenate attribute columns
        ReDim thisArr(1 To lastrow - 1, 1 To 4)
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            j = 1
                thisArr(i - 1, 1) = sourceWS.Cells(i, readcols(j))
            For j = 2 To 7
                thisArr(i - 1, 1) = thisArr(i - 1, 1) & "|" & sourceWS.Cells(i, readcols(j))
            Next j
            j = 8
                thisArr(i - 1, 2) = sourceWS.Cells(i, readcols(j))
            j = 9
                thisArr(i - 1, 3) = sourceWS.Cells(i, readcols(j))
            j = 2
                thisArr(i - 1, 4) = sourceWS.Cells(i, readcols(j)) 'currency entered again in its own column for easy lookup later
        Next i

        'close file
        sourceWB.Close savechanges:=False

        'sort array
        Call quicksort(thisArr, 1, 1, UBound(thisArr, 1))

        'get risk free shocks: array is in format [Currency TermBucket]
        Dim riskFree() As Variant
        ReDim riskFree(1 To UBound(currToRiskFree), 1 To UBound(termBuckets) + 1)
        For i = 1 To UBound(riskFree, 1)

            riskFree(i, 1) = currToRiskFree(i, 1)

            For thisBucket = 1 To UBound(termBuckets)

                thisArrRow = findInArrCol(currToRiskFree(i, 2) & "|" & termBuckets(thisBucket) & "||SHOCK", 1, thisArr)

                If thisArrRow = 0 Then
                    MsgBox ("Error calculating risk free rate: Could not find " & riskFree(i, 2) & "|" & termBuckets(thisBucket) & "||SHOCK in" & scenNames(thisScen, 1))
                    Exit Sub
                End If

                'absolute shock
                If thisArr(thisArrRow, 3) = "non-parallel shift" Then
                    riskFree(i, thisBucket + 1) = thisArr(thisArrRow, 2) * 10000


                'relative shock
                ElseIf thisArr(thisArrRow, 3) = "variable factor" Then
                    thisCurveMapRow = findInArrCol(currToRiskFree(i, 2), 1, curveNameToMarketData) 'get mapping market data curve name
                    thisCurveDataRow = findInArrCol(curveNameToMarketData(thisCurveMapRow, 2), 2, curveData) 'get curve data

                    'absolute shock = 10000 * abs(yield) * (relative shock - 1)
                    riskFree(i, thisBucket + 1) = 10000 * Abs(curveData(thisCurveDataRow, 2 + thisBucket)) * (thisArr(thisArrRow, 2) - 1)


                'special case for SRF credit scenarios
                ElseIf thisArr(thisArrRow, 3) = "NOT DEFINED" And (scenNames(thisScen, 1) = "Credit_Spread_Pos_Basis" Or scenNames(thisScen, 1) = "Credit_Spread_Neg_Basis" Or scenNames(thisScen, 1) = "Credit_Spread_Zero_Basis") Then
                    riskFree(i, thisBucket + 1) = 0

                Else
                    MsgBox ("Error calculating risk free rate: Code can not handle Shock Type " & thisArr(thisArrRow, 3) & " for " & currToRiskFree(i, 2) & " in " & scenNames(thisScen, 1))
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next thisBucket
        Next i

        Call quicksort(riskFree, 1, 1, UBound(riskFree, 1))

        'step through each curve and calculate shocks
        For thisCurve = 1 To UBound(curveNames, 1)

            arrshocks(thisRow, 1) = "IR"
            arrshocks(thisRow + 1, 1) = "CR"
            arrshocks(thisRow, 2) = scenNames(thisScen, 1)
            arrshocks(thisRow + 1, 2) = scenNames(thisScen, 1)
            arrshocks(thisRow, 3) = curveNames(thisCurve, 1)
            arrshocks(thisRow + 1, 3) = curveNames(thisCurve, 1)

            For thisBucket = 1 To UBound(termBuckets, 1)

                'find curve in array
                thisArrRow = findInArrCol(curveNames(thisCurve, 1) & "|" & termBuckets(thisBucket) & "||SHOCK", 1, thisArr)

                If thisArrRow = 0 Then 'could not find curve in array

                    arrshocks(thisRow, 3 + thisBucket) = "ERROR: Could not find curve in scenario file"
                    arrshocks(thisRow + 1, 3 + thisBucket) = "ERROR: Could not find curve in scenario file"

                Else
                    'write shock to array
                    thisRiskFreeRow = findInArrCol(thisArr(thisArrRow, 4), 1, riskFree)

                    'absolute shock
                    If thisArr(thisArrRow, 3) = "non-parallel shift" Then

                        'arrshocks(thisrow, 3 + thisBucket) = thisArr(thisArrRow, 2) * 10000 'TOTAL SHOCK
                        arrshocks(thisRow, 3 + thisBucket) = riskFree(thisRiskFreeRow, thisBucket + 1) 'IR SHOCK
                        arrshocks(thisRow + 1, 3 + thisBucket) = thisArr(thisArrRow, 2) * 10000 - arrshocks(thisRow, 3 + thisBucket) 'CR SHOCK


                    'relative shock
                    ElseIf thisArr(thisArrRow, 3) = "variable factor" Then

                        thisCurveMapRow = findInArrCol(curveNames(thisCurve, 1), 1, curveNameToMarketData) 'get mapping market data curve name
                        thisCurveDataRow = findInArrCol(curveNameToMarketData(thisCurveMapRow, 2), 2, curveData) 'get curve data

                        'absolute shock = 10000 * abs(yield) * (relative shock - 1)
                        'arrshocks(thisrow, 3 + thisBucket) = 10000 * Abs(curveData(thisCurveDataRow, 1 + thisBucket)) * (thisArr(thisArrRow, 2) - 1) 'TOTAL SHOCK
                        arrshocks(thisRow, 3 + thisBucket) = riskFree(thisRiskFreeRow, thisBucket + 1) 'IR SHOCK
                        arrshocks(thisRow + 1, 3 + thisBucket) = 10000 * Abs(curveData(thisCurveDataRow, 2 + thisBucket)) * (thisArr(thisArrRow, 2) - 1) - arrshocks(thisRow, 3 + thisBucket)


                    'special case for SRF credit scenarios
                    ElseIf thisArr(thisArrRow, 3) = "NOT DEFINED" And (scenNames(thisScen, 1) = "Credit_Spread_Pos_Basis" Or scenNames(thisScen, 1) = "Credit_Spread_Neg_Basis" Or scenNames(thisScen, 1) = "Credit_Spread_Zero_Basis") Then
                        arrshocks(thisRow, 3 + thisBucket) = 0
                        arrshocks(thisRow + 1, 3 + thisBucket) = 0
                    Else
                        arrshocks(thisRow, 1) = "IR - ERROR"
                        arrshocks(thisRow, 3 + thisBucket) = "ERROR: Shock Type '" & thisArr(thisArrRow, 3) & "' not coded for in this subroutine"
                        arrshocks(thisRow + 1, 1) = "CR - ERROR"
                        arrshocks(thisRow + 1, 3 + thisBucket) = "ERROR: Shock Type '" & thisArr(thisArrRow, 3) & "' not coded for in this subroutine"
                    End If

                End If

            Next thisBucket

        thisRow = thisRow + 2

        Next thisCurve
    Next thisScen


    'create file and save array data to it
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells.ClearContents
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Shock type"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 2).Value = "Scenario"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 3).Value = "Curve"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 4).Value = "0"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 5).Value = "30"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 6).Value = "91"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 7).Value = "182"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 8).Value = "365"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 9).Value = "730"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 10).Value = "1095"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 11).Value = "1461"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 12).Value = "1826"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 13).Value = "2556"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 14).Value = "3652"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 15).Value = "5478"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 16).Value = "7305"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 17).Value = "10957"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Cells(1, 18).Value = "21914"

    Call writeArrToWS(arrshocks, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks").Range("A2"), True, UBound(arrshocks, 1), UBound(arrshocks, 2))




End Sub
```

Adding one of the call subs:

```
Public Sub writeArrToWS(arr() As Variant, startCell As Range, fromTop As Boolean, nRows As Long, nCols As Long)


    Dim i As Long, j As Long, startRow As Long, startCol As Long
    Dim thisWS As Worksheet
    Dim writeVal As Variant

    Set thisWS = startCell.Worksheet

    startRow = startCell.row
    startCol = startCell.Column

    'clear
    For i = 1 To nRows
        For j = 1 To nCols
            thisWS.Cells(startRow + i - 1, startCol + j - 1).value = ""
        Next j
    Next i

    'write
    For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.Min(nRows, UBound(arr, 1))
        For j = 1 To nCols
            If fromTop Then writeVal = arr(i, j) Else writeVal = arr(UBound(arr, 1) - i + 1, j)
            thisWS.Cells(startRow + i - 1, startCol + j - 1).value = writeVal
        Next j
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: I am having trouble picturing the intent (like @RyanWildry). As such, I don't understand why such complex constructs like `ReDim arrshocks(1 To UBound(scenNames) * UBound(curveNames) * 2, 1 To 3 + UBound(termBuckets))` which might introduce an unnecessarily large array and loop.

Comment: ... and your `quicksort` routine is missing. The fact that you `Call` it implies inefficient use of a routine - this could be part of your issue. You call it 2+2*#scenames times!

Comment: @AJD , i added writeArrToWs. Kind of hard to describe intent, thought maybe you could help speed up the array issues, variable declaration issues, and workbook name in loop issues.

Comment: This is [off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if you don't explain *what* you're doing, rather than the issues you have. Especially considering this code is very obfuscated in the first place.

Comment: X-Y problem? If we understood how this routine was called, could probably suggest a way of bypassing it altogether!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*This answer will be added to as more information becomes available*]

### writeArrToWS

```
Public Sub writeArrToWS(arr() As Variant, startCell As Range, fromTop As Boolean, nRows As Long, nCols As Long)
```

This is very inefficient. Given that you only call it once in you main routine, there is no requirement for so many parameters.

I am still not sure what you are trying to achieve with `arrshocks` (a 2-dimensional array) and thus cannot reconcile what you are doing with `nCols`. This obfuscation makes it hard to provide advice. Consider using an array of arrays, rather than an array of values. The following code assumes that your use of `nCol` was logical (which I doubt).

```
Public Sub writeArrToWS(arr() As Variant, startCell As Range)
    Dim targetRange as Range
    Set targetRange = startCell ' assumes startCell is a single cell. Could do error checking here!
    targetRange.resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2))
    targetRange.ClearContents ' don't even think this is necessary.
    targetRange = arr
End Sub
```

*** Not tested, so any minor bugs in the code are up to you to tweak

Given the contortions I see here, I would have created a custom object. Perhaps a consideration for yourself as well - might make your intent clearer.

Comment: is this meant to replace the whole `WriteArrtoWs`code? If so I  I've stepped through and usually gets excel not responding at the `write` area of this sub. I do get error on this line , `targetRange.resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2))`

Comment: @excelguy: as noted, not tested because I don't have anything that resembles the original data or arrays. If you are not using a 2-D array, then I guess it would error out. What error did you get?